# Best solution for team managment

Tags: communication, documentation, task-management

We are using three tools for handle our jobs,

**Slack** for communication

**Trello** for Task Management

**Google Docs** for Documentation

because these tools have not good integration with each other ( and also we need better task management system) we are looking for a tool that satisfy our requirements in best way

**Our requirements**

1. Documenation
2. Task and Project Manager
3. Communication

We found some solutions

[Atlassian Family](https://www.atlassian.com/try) ( Jira + Hipchat + confluence )

[Biritx24](http://bitrix24.com/)

[Podio](http://podio.com/)

[Exoplatform](https://www.exoplatform.com/)

we are really getting confused what is best solution for us(**we looking for a tool that provided all of requirements in one**)?

we are a company with several departments ( our jobs is around web) and at this time we have 15 users ( but we'll grow up)

appreciate any help

Comment: What's your tech stack look like? (I know, it *shouldn't* matter, but it does.)

Comment: Software recommendations are off-topic here. You may want to ask on [Software Recs Stack Exchange](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/) instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Documentation - Git + Confluence.
2. Task and Project Manager - Jira.
3. Communication - Slack + Google hangouts.

Comment: thank you for ettention Alexander, but we need all in one package. ( our porblem now is that we are use 3 source that integration between them is not easy and confidence)

Comment: Hi @zhilevan, slack has integration with everything https://slack.com/apps.
It also has custom integration mechanism https://api.slack.com/custom-integrations . Hip chat sucks, both in UI/UX and integration.

Answer (score 1):

Considering your requirements, I'd definitely fork up money for the Atlassian stack.

Confluence + JIRA + HipChat integrate *really* well and Confluence and JIRA are very flexible tools.

If you take the on-premise versions though. it's a bit of a step-up in terms of administration effort and cost from your current solutions.

Alternatively, if 2/3 + 1/3 is OK, consider GitLab, GitHub or BitBucket with the Wiki in the Git repo, and use Slack for communication.